# Generating a circular pattern in a random vector field

Tags: c++

So I'm having difficulty creating a randomized vector field in C++ (with OpenGL).

I want the general field to be random where vx and vy are 2D random directional vectors for the field. Then, I want a general circular pattern to be put into the field with center (cx, cy).

Here's my code so far:

```
void makePattern()
{
  int i, j, x, y, g;

  // randomize vector field generation variables
  parm1 = 0.01 * (double)(rand()%100);
  parm2 = 0.01 * (double)(rand()%100);
  parm3 = 0.01 * (double)(rand()%100);
  signx = rand()%2;
  signy = rand()%2;
  if ( signx != 1 )
    signx = -1;
  if ( signy != 1 )
    signy = -1;

  // randomize circle center
  cx = rand()%(XSIZE);
  cy = rand()%(YSIZE);

  for ( i = 0; i < XSIZE; i++ )
  {
    for ( j = 0; j < YSIZE; j++ )
    {
      // CREATE RANDOM FIELD
      x = i*0.15f + parm3*(i+j)*0.1f + parm3*20.0f -10.0f;
      y = j*0.4f - 40.0f*parm1;
      vx[i][j] = 0.5f*parm2  + sin(0.12f*y) ;
      vy[i][j] = 0.9f* sin(parm1*x)+ 2.5f*sin(0.1*x) + 3.0f*sin(0.06f*x)*
          cos(y*0.03f)+ 2.7f*sin(0.015f*x)*(1.0f*0.5f*cos(y/50.0f));

      vx[i][j] *= signx * 0.25f; 
      vy[i][j] *= signy * 0.25f;

      // MAKE THE CIRCLE PATTERN; NOT WORKING
      x = i - cx;
      y = j - cy;
      g = exp( -(x*x + y*y) );
      vx[i][j] += y*g;
      vy[i][j] += (-x)*g;
    }
  }

}
```

This is the result when I draw random particles over a short lifespan:

[image: Random Vector Field]

Unfortunately, there's no clear defined circle in the pattern, in fact, there's a couple of little circles I'd prefer to get rid of. I'm trying to figure out the math behind the first half of the nested for-loop, as it was given to me with only the explanation that it would create a randomized vector field. Otherwise, the circle generating portion is supposed to take the current cell's distance from the center of the circle and change the direction of that cell to accommodate the curve of the circle, but it actually does nothing for the scene; the scene stays the same with or without the code.